# Trouble Changing Angular Routing

Tags: angular, routes

New to angular and js frameworks in general. I'm working with this tutorial: [http://nitsuga.com/](http://nitsuga.com/blog/2018/01/23/build-a-master-details-angular-application/)

I have  the tutorial up and running on my machine just fine, but now I'd like to change the URL parameter to navigate to the "details" to not be the product id (p.id) but something else, like the name of the product. Just to experiment I added a JSON name/value of `"dname":"name-with-dashes"`.

My products in `products.ts` now look like this

```
    { id: 1, name: 'Medavac Survival Kit', **dname: 'medavac-survival',** type: 'Camping Gear', status: 'In stock', price: 14.99, description: 'Comes in a waterproof case. Includes fire starter, compass, wire saw, emergency whistle, can opener, suture thread and needle, bandages and more!' },
```

In `selected-product.pipe.ts` I edited the code to be:

```
export class SelectedProductPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(allProducts: Product[], productId: string): any {
        return allProducts.filter(p => p.dname === productId);
    }
}
```

In `product-list.component.html` I changed the router link to

```
[routerLink]="['/product-details', p.dname]"
```

In `product-details.component.html` I changed the loop to

```
*ngFor="let p of (products | selectedProduct: dname)"
```

And `product-details.component.ts` now looks like this:

```
export class ProductDetailsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    private id: number;
    **private dname: string;**
    products: Product[];
    private sub: any;

    prodIdSnapshot: number;

    constructor(private productService: ProductService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
        this.products = productService.getProducts();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
          **this.dname = +params['dname'];**
        });
    }
```

But I the details page remains blank, and I get this error in my editor for the `product-details.component.ts` (above):

> "Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)."

Here is stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tt9xkg

Comment: Can you share Stackblitz ?

Comment: Here is the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tt9xkg

Comment: i don't see any exception in this

Comment: Sorry, I was being unclear. What I'm looking to do: When the user clicks on a product, such as "Medavac Survival Kit" it should route to the product-details.component.html and grab the associated data. On the stackblitz the product-details page is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this Will work: `this.dname = params['dname'];`.
So, remove the + sign in that line.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but that didn't seem to solve my problem. Here is a stackblitz I made if it helps: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tt9xkg

Comment: Its the pipe. You pass it a dName and compare it in the filter with the id. If you pass in the id or compare with dName you get your detail data.

So in product-detials-component.html do `*ngFor="let p of (products | selectedProduct: id)` instead of `*ngFor="let p of (products | selectedProduct: dname)`

Comment: Yes -- that did it. Thank you! It was the combination of removing the "+" sign and actually comparing the same data in the pipe, naturally. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Adding '+' will coerce a string as a number.

Below snippet should be fine

```
this.dname = params['dname'];
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but that didn't seem to solve my problem. Here is a stackblitz I made if it helps: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tt9xkg